# Issue with accessing controllers in routes in my Hapi app

Tags: hapi.js

New to Hapi, writing my first app.
I have my routes and controllers in separate files inside each module. So far, I had been requiring controllers in my routes file like:

```
const controller = require('./controller');
```

and then writing routes like:

```
module.exports = [{
    path: '/items/{id}',
    method: 'GET',
    handler: controller.getItemById
}];
```

So far so good.

Now, I want to start using caching in my controller methods. This forced me to convert my controller into a plugin.

So my controller now looks like:

```
exports.register = (server, options, next) => {

    const itemCache = (id, itemId) => {
        // do caching stuff
    }

    const getItemById = (request, reply) => {
    // do stuff, use itemCache
    }

    server.expose({
        getItemById: getItemById
    });

    next();
};
```

The question is, now how do I access the controller in my routes file? server.dependency() is not available to the routes file.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also new to Hapi though I would say the best and most standard way to handle this in Hapi would be to either

A) make routes it's own plugin too so the server gets passed through

or

B) Make the only export of the routes index file a function that accepts the server as a parameter. and returns the routes for the server. Call it after creating your server in your main index file.

Also keep in mind that if you just need the server object in your controllers for functions that will be handlers for your routes you can get the server object from the request parameter passed in to those functions. (ps this is Lana from the gitter board :P)